# how to append data continuously in data frame depending upon the number of times function is called

Tags: python, pandas

**UseCase:**

I have an xml file, from which i am parsing some values as per their attributes  and storing them in dictionary format.

Function add_data_to_data_frame is overwriting the data frame each time it is being called.

I want that data should be appended not overwrite while calling the function.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
date=pd.to_datetime(date)

def add_data_to_dataframe():
    data={
        'fail':5,
        'Pass':5,
        'suite_name':['Robot'],
        'Report_datetime':[pd.to_datetime('today').now()],
        'datetime':[pd.to_datetime('today').now()]
        }
    rd=pd.DataFrame(columns=['suite_name','fail','Pass','Report_datetime','datetime'],index=[date])
    rd=pd.DataFrame(data,index=[date])
    rd=rd.append(pd.DataFrame(data,index=[date]))
    return rd

dq=add_data_to_dataframe()
print (dq)
```

Each time when the function is called , i got 2 output

```
    Pass         Report_datetime                datetime  fail  \
2017-11-13     5 2017-11-13 15:51:51.648 2017-11-13 15:51:51.648     5   
2017-11-13     5 2017-11-13 15:51:51.648 2017-11-13 15:51:51.648     5   

           suite_name  
2017-11-13      Robot  
2017-11-13      Robot
```

What i want is that if next time I call my function there should be 3 records in it and so on

Comment: So I am having a difficult time grasping what you want to do here! can you explain a bit more clearly

Comment: Please see the edits

Comment: Why do you want to make this thing so complex? I mean if there is an easier way to do it by just returning dict from `add_data_to_dataframe()` function and then appending it to a list after that you can append the list to dataframe and you wont loose anything

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The reason its overwriting is you are using same variable name and performing the append operation inside the function which will empty everything when you call it for second time.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

rd=pd.DataFrame() # an empty dataframe
date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
date=pd.to_datetime(date)

def add_data_to_dataframe():
    data={
        'fail':5,
        'Pass':5,
        'suite_name':['Robot'],
        'Report_datetime':[pd.to_datetime('today').now()],
        'datetime':[pd.to_datetime('today').now()]
        }
       empty_list.append(data)
       return empty_list
```

After I get the empty list I will define my dataframe

```
make_list = add_data_to_dataframe()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(make_list,columns=['suite_name','fail','Pass','Report_datetime','datetime'],index=[date])
```

Now at the end append both the dataframes.

```
rd.append(new_df) # now instead of overwriting it will append
```

Comment: Will let you know

Comment: i modified your code at very minor level to make it running , however output of "rd" dataframe is still overwriting

Comment: Can u please try and append it to a list and at the very end you can make a dataframe